# How to expand decimal places of a number to a minimum in Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, formatting, numbers

I cant figure out how to select the following:

```
123        -> 123.00000
123.12     -> 123.12000
123.123456 -> 123.123456
```

I would like to expand the number of decimal places to for example 5 decimal places (minimum)
If there are no decimal places at all there should be 5 zeros.
It is fine if there are more then 5 decimal places.

```
SELECT ROUND(123,5) FROM DUAL;
```

will result: 123
instead of 123.00000

The number has a default precision.

Is this possible or should I convert it to a varchar with the [oracle number formats](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-numfmt.html)?

I am using Oracle 10g with plsql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
SQL> SELECT X, to_char(X, 'fm99999999.00000999')
  2    FROM (SELECT 123 X FROM dual UNION ALL
  3          SELECT 123.12 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4          SELECT 123.123456 FROM dual);

         X TO_CHAR(X,'FM99999999.00000999
---------- ------------------------------
       123 123.00000
    123.12 123.12000
123.123456 123.123456
```

Comment: what if I have a decimal number like 00.71? With your method, I would get .71 but I want 0.71.

Comment: @dev.mi Use `fm99999990.00`, see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert it to a Varchar as follows:

```
SELECT to_char(123, '9999.99999') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to FORMAT the data, you have to use the to_char function. in numeric values trailing zeroes are truncated (they are irrelevant).