# Appending '0' after decimal in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I want to append trailing '0' to number while performing Select query:

what I want is to select

> 344.89 as 344.890
>
> 123213.45 as 123213.450
>
> 1.2 as 1.200

I tried using
`to_char(col_name,'000000.000')` but that resulted in

> 344.89 => 000344.890
>
> 123213.45 => 123213.450
>
> 1.2 => 000001.200

there were unwanted '0' appended to the result.

Comment: What should happen with `344.891` or `344.8901`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662153/how-to-expand-decimal-places-of-a-number-to-a-minimum-in-oracle-plsql

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662153/how-to-expand-decimal-places-of-a-number-to-a-minimum-in-oracle-plsql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are close with the `to_char` format.  Try this:

```
to_char(col_name,'999999.000')
```

The `9`s represent optional place holders.  The `0`s represent putting in leading zeros.

Comment: That is working fine, so there can't be solution for any number of digits before the decimal, as in this solution there will be a problem if there are more than 6 digits before decimal. say 2749308.23